# Modify the URL wihout reloading the page

Tags: jquery

I know that there were similar topics, but I still didn't get the working solution. I want to send the `$.post` method to the server and before it I want to modify the URL (to allow the users to share the URLs by each other) but without reloading the page. How to do it ?

**Edit**:  In other words, I want to make the `$.post` method to filter the data displayed on the page. But also I want to modify the URL that user can copy it.

Comment: In modern browsers, you can use HTML5's [`History.pushState`](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate).

Comment: But this would modify the history, not the current url.

Comment: @Armin: There is [`History.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState().C2.A0method) that will just change the current URL without pushing onto the history.

Comment: Rocket, I saw folks discussing how github does this on SO not too long ago, perhaps this is how they are doing it (History.replaceState)?  If you go here for example https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic and click on the /docs or /src folder you should see the URL update to reflect what has changed -- without reloading the page.  As you mentioned this only works /w modern browsers.

Comment: @mikey: That is exactly how [GitHub is doing it](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) :-)  They're using `pushState` to change the URL, and using AJAX to load the new page contents.

Answer (score 2):

If your users are using a modern browser (pretty much anything that's not IE), you can use the new HTML5 [history methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).  Specifically, [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method).

`replaceState()` will change the URL of the page without re-loading it.  You can use it like this:

```
$.post('/some/url/', {some: data}, function(d){
    // Do whatever with the returned data...

    // Change page URL
    history.replaceState({}, '', '/some/url/');
});
```

Or you can change the URL before loading the data:

```
// Change page URL
history.replaceState({}, '', '/some/url/');
// load page data
$.post('/some/url/', {some: data}, function(d){
    // Do whatever with the returned data...
});
```

For an example of `replaceState`, go here: https://github.com/features/projects, and click on the 4 tabs.  Watch the URL change, but nothing's added to the history :-)

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. So, if the user uses the IE, the URL will not change ?

Comment: @Tony: Nope.  `history.replaceState` doesn't work in IE.  You should add `if(!!(window.history && window.history.replaceState))` around the `replaceState` calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The only part in the url you can modify without a reload is the part after the # (hash a.k.a. fragment). The whole rest before would initiate the load of the new (or old) url.

You can change it (with reload) with the following javascript:

```
location.href = 'http://www.whatever.com';
```

Comment: You can't modify the `action` attribute on the form element?

Comment: You could, but is it, what he wants?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but it sounds like he wants to change the URL of the `POST` action before actually posting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id='urltocopy'></div>
    ...
</body>

function doPost() {
    $('#urltocopy').html('<a href="http://newurltocopy">Please copy</a>');

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlStr,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {

            },
            data: {},

        });
}
```